# How do I get rid of the white space between the footer and the portfolio?

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to get rid of the white space in between the footer and the portfolio. The website is Creationflame.com

The website developers said that this code line was causing the problem. I can't find the code at all even where to delete this line but I'm also unsure if this is exactly what's causing it on the home page. So far that's the only issue.

```
div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid edgtf-section edgtf-content-aligment-left" style="">
```

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeGze.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a negative margin to the content section above the footer, you can remove the white space.

This worked for me:

`.edgtf-full-width-inner{
 margin-bottom: -4.8%;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You have a div with class "decom_dop_bloc" which contains comment section.
This is the cause of the blank white space.